# Need to pass the value of the variable php to javascript but I can not

Tags: javascript, php

**I need to pass the value of the variable php to javascript but I can not**.
Try many forms and does not work.
work with the following versions and not whether the cause of the failure.
Apache 2.2.25 and PHP 5.2.17 (I need to work For Now With These Versions).
The value that should receive the variable in the example is "kml/Aechmea_magdalenae.kml"

```
$anio = $row['kml_map'];
```

```
        <script>

            function initialize() {
              var mexico = new google.maps.LatLng(20.6568241,-103.3984801);
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                center: mexico
              }

              var url2 = <?php echo json_encode($anio) ?>;
              var url1 = 'http://www.cnf.gob.mx:8090/snif/especies_forestales/';
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);     
              var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: url1+url2});
              ctaLayer.setMap(map);}

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Comment: Hi Frederic, I do like that too, But Not Working .

Comment: Show us the output of `json_encode($anio);`, it could well be because of its value being encoded or escaped that you're having this rather vaguely described issue

Comment: try printing the value of url1 and url2 with an alert but shows nothing.
alert (url1+url2);

and do not know how to fix it , not because it is the variable receives

Comment: **show** us the value of `$anio`, if only by using a simple `var_dump($anio); exit();` or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this line:

```
var url2 = <?php echo json_encode($anio) ?>;
```

If you intend to json_encode (i think is the other way), you should use quotes, some like

```
var url2 = "<?php echo json_encode($anio) ?>";
```

Comment: You definitely ***don't*** want to add quotes, seeing as a json encoded object already contains double quotes, and equally so because JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, hence => output of `json_encode` is valid JavaScript code

Comment: But if you try to append an object to text like he does later, without knowing the expected format of URL, the safer is to assume a String

Comment: In that case, either check the string, and echo it directly (skipping `json_encode`, which escapes forward slashes), or use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` constant (cf my answer + demo)

Comment: Thanks for all!
Change the version of php and this solution eliminate the problem
PHP 5.2 - 5.4 o sup.

Answer (score 1):

As you can [see here](https://eval.in/248370), echoing a `json_encoded` url string will escape the forward slashes in that url. 
The solution then is *either* to do:

```
var url = '<?php echo $anio; ?>';
```

Making sure that the value of `$anio` does not contain any single quotes, or (if you're running PHP 5.4 or up), to use this:

```
var url = <?php echo json_encode($anio, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES); ?>;
```

Note the lack of quotes (`json_encode` will add quotes for you), and the use of the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` constant. [check the manual for more constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

## [demo/PoC here](https://eval.in/248376)

Comment: Thanks! Change the version of php and this solution eliminate the problem

Comment: @LuisGuerra: If _this_ solution solved the problem, then why did you mark the other answer as accepted?